# do we need to define serialVersionUID in app specific exceptions

Tags: java, spring-boot

I know `serialVersionUID` is used serialization and deserialization. I read [What is a serialVersionUID and why should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/what-is-a-serialversionuid-and-why-should-i-use-it)

So if we are using distributed cache like hazelcast or coherence or redis we need serialVersionUID. Example entity or VO classes needs that. My question is little bit further.

Do we need to define that for app specific **exception** in spring boot application no EJB no weblogic no websphere, regular tomcat no distributed cache or session sharing exist, just an instance of spring boot application rest services no UI. example

```
public class MyBusinessException extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7718828512143293558L;
    public MyBusinessException() {
        super();
    }
}
```

I have never seen an app specific excpetion deserialized before in prod or anywhere. So do we really need `serialVersionUID` here ?

Comment: Yes.   But you can write `private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;` in every single exception class.

Comment: then what's the point? jvm is automatically generating serialversion id anyway, why do I have to write in the class ? with value 1 or random

Comment: The point is that you need to tell Java which versions of your class are compatible with previously serialized versions.  If you let Java compute a serialVersionUID, then *every single change* you make to the class will cause it to be incompatible with serialized versions of the same class with even the slightest of differences.

Comment: good, when was the last time did you serialize an application/business specific exception?

Comment: The last time I used EJBs.  Exceptions thrown by their public methods need to be serializable for seamless clustering to work.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention this is spring boot environment, no ejbs, can you tell any example for that ?

Comment: I’m not sure about Spring’s serializability requirements.  Here are two other ways to approach this:  1. Adding one line of code is quite easy, so why not do it?  2. Object-oriented development means that implementing an interface is more than just writing required public methods;  the interface is not properly implemented until its contract is honored, and that means writing classes which are reliably serializable, if they claim to be serializable.

Comment: 1. I like to add it for entity and value objects those used in distributed caching or any serialization and deserialization. I personally love serializable objects because I can trust them with hazelcast. my main point is exceptions, I don't see the point we need verdion in exceptions especially in spring boot backend no distirbuted cache, I hope you got my point